# Bootstrap table row hover with exceptions of some rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table that supports hovering via `class="table-hover"`. However, I want certain rows (that have different colours) not to be highlighted upon hovering.

I have copied the hover rule from bootstrap and adjusted to it tr.no-hover:

```
.table-hover tbody tr.no-hover:hover > td,
.table-hover tbody tr.no-hover:hover > th {
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

My idea was, that this way it should display the orginal (ie. unhovered) colour of the row, since I wanted the `no-hover` to genericly apply to differently coloured rows. But that did not work. Neither did specifying `transparent` as colour.

Essentially, what I need is to remove the hover-effect on some rows. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: please post a fiddle.

Comment: Looks good: http://plnkr.co/edit/G4lvVb0TPTwLsIwNVyd0?p=preview.

Comment: He wants it for different colors like `.success, .warning` etc. and in this case i guess you have to do this once per class.

Comment: seem's like my idea wasn't too bad after all. Unfortunately, this means I'll have to find out in which way my page differs from the provided plunker example :( Thnaks @dfsq

Comment: If you want to be selective, would it be easier to not use bootstrap's table-hover class, and instead just add your own css to add hover  effects what you want?

Comment: I thought the same already, @Will. I just hoped there would be a way.

Comment: Like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/INuppBzm7r4r7bqvCJm5?p=preview

Comment: @Will, please post your idea with separate hover just for the rows that require a hover effect as answer. I'll accept it, since it tackeles the problem from a direction that is easier to handle.

Comment: Thanks @omike, I created an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you need to be more selective in terms of which rows you want the hover effect applied to, it's probably easier to create your own CSS hover effects rather than using bootstrap's table-hover class.

Demo (thanks dfsq for the base):  http://plnkr.co/edit/INuppBzm7r4r7bqvCJm5?p=preview

You can use the following CSS (using not selector) to apply a background color on hover to table rows without a specific class.

CSS:

```
tr:not(.no-hover):hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

For everyone interested how to get this to work, I found a solution which works with removing the hover-effect without specifying a seperate hover-colour for each colour in use.

http://plnkr.co/edit/phGI6csBqmOXML1spLV4?p=preview

The key point here is to set the custom colour on the tr element, that way the cells will be coloured correctly and additionally with

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr.no-hover:hover > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.no-hover:hover > th {
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

what is inherited, is the colour of the tr.

Unfortunately I don't have an IE at hand to test its behaviour.

This is especially useful, when you use custom colours in some of your table rows and the rest should be Bootstrap's default colours. That way you don't have to replicate Bootstrap's hover colour.

Comment: Nice, clean solution! Thank you!

Comment: I had to add .table-hover tbody tr:hover to your css selection too

Answer (score 0):

```
.table-hover tbody tr.no-hover.success:hover > td,
.table-hover tbody tr.no-hover.success:hover > th {
    background-color: $brand-success;
}

.table-hover tbody tr.no-hover.warning:hover > td,
.table-hover tbody tr.no-hover.warning:hover > th {
    background-color: $brand-warning;
}
```

and so on, i would say...

Comment: To me it seems like a little too much effort, since this would actually require an additional hover-definition per different colour.

Answer (score 0):

I could only get this to work with bootstrap by setting a no-hover background color, and using this in **both** the *tr* and *td* class definitions:

```
<tr class='no-hover'><td class='no-hover'>Some Text</td></tr>

.no-hover {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

If you want to specify the hover color also, you can add:

```
.table-hover tbody tr:not(.no-hover):hover td, .table-hover tbody tr:not(.no-hover):hover th {
    background-color: green;
}
```